# How to loop through indexedDB tables synchronously?

Tags: html, indexeddb

I want to write a function in JS where I will loop through a tables in my indexed DB and get the maximum value of last modified of table and return that

```
function readData(){
    var trans = '';
    trans = idb.transaction(["tableName"],'readonly'); // Create the transaction
    var request = trans.objectStore("tableName").openCursor();
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        var cursor = request.result || e.result; 
        if(cursor) {
            // logic to  and find maximum
        } else {
            return // max last modified
        }
        cursor.continue();
    }
}
```

IMP--Since onsuccess method is asynchronous how can i make it synchronous? so that my method readData() will return only when max last modified record is found successfully. I can call this method(readData()) synchronously to get last modified record of 2-3 tables if I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sync API is only available in a webworker. So this would be the first requirement. (As far as I know only IE10 supports this at the moment)

An other shot you can give is working with JS 1.7 and use the yield keyword. For more information about it look [here](http://tobyho.com/2010/12/10/trampolines-in-javascript-and/)

I would sugest to work with a callbakck method that you call when you reached the latest value.

```
function readData(callback){     
   var trans = '';         
   trans = idb.transaction(["tableName"],'readonly'); //Create the transaction   
   var request = trans.objectStore("tableName").openCursor();
   var maxKey;      
   request.onsuccess = function(e) {   
       var cursor = request.result || e.result;             
       if(cursor.value){             
          //logic to  and find maximum
          maxKey = cursor.primaryKey            
          cursor.continue();
       }
   } 
   trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
        callback(maxKey); 
   }
}
```

Comment: No browser implements the sync API, even in a web worker. AFAIK, only chrome supports indexeddb in a web worker at all, and that's just the async API.

Comment: this won't work cause variable maxKey is declared inside on success event on the cursor which is called every time on cursor continue. I've submitted edit to your code please review it.

Comment: Why not use key range with `var request = trans.objectStore("tableName").openCursor(null, 'prev');` The first result will be the last key inserted.

Comment: correct, but you still need to iterate evey record. So this way it won't make a lot of difference

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB API in top frame is async. async cannot be synchronous. But you can read all tables in single transaction.

Comment: How can I read all table in single transaction?? Please post an example..I will be thankful..

Comment: open `trans` for all stores, `db.transaction(db.objectStoreNames, IDBTransaction.readonly)`, read data through repeatedly opening stores `trans.objectStore(db.objectStoreNames[i]).openCursor()` trans will not commit until all you finish.  It should work as long as you run synchronously inside the transaction, I haven't try thought.